# Implementation of a Generic BST

Tags: java

Hello I would like to know how to set up an object oriented BST class that has a private Node class.(Both classes being generic)
so far I have this but i am having some compilation errors. Some explanation would be nice. I copied this code, but I know there are mistakes to fix. Also how would you set up the constructor of the bst?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private Node <T> root;
    //  public BST(){
    //      root=null;
    //  }

    private T search(T target, BST <T> p)
    {

        int comp=target.compareTo(p.data);
        T c=target.compareTo(P.data);
        if(comp==0)
            return c;
    }


    private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable {
        T data;
        Node<T> left, right;

        public Node(T t)
        {
            data=t; 
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator iterator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public T search(T target)
        {
            return search(target, root);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor should be fine that you've originally commented out should be fine. Is there a particular use case you have in mind that it doesn't satisfy?

Something like this. Because the Node class is a private inner class, it doesn't have to be generic and can instead use the type specified in its parent class, which is what I assume you want anyway.

The node class doesn't really need a search method because it only contains one value. There's no need to search if there's just one value. This is also the same reason it doesn't need a iterator either. There's really no need to iterate over just one value.

When designing an abstract data type such as a BST, it's good to consider how you envision it will be used: what operations should it support, aka. its API. The implementation below supports 2 operations: insert and search. Possible extensions might include a remove and/or a contains operation.

Operations on a tree are typically recursive. This is because you start at the root and have to traverse through inner nodes which themselves can be viewed as roots of their respective subtrees. Try walking through a few example inserts and searches to convince yourself why it works that way.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Node root;

    public BST(){
        root=null;
    }

    private void insertInternal(T value, Node parent) {
        int comp=value.compareTo(parent.data);
        if(comp < 0) {
            if(parent.left == null) {
                parent.left = new Node(value);
            }
            else {
                insertInternal(value, parent.left);
            }
        }
        else if(comp > 0) {
            if(parent.right == null) {
                parent.right = new Node(value);
            }
            else {
                insertInternal(value, parent.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public void insert(T value) {
        if(root == null) {
            root = new Node(value);
            return;
        }
        insertInternal(value, root);
    }

    private Node searchInternal(T target, Node node) {
        if(node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int comp=target.compareTo(node.data);
        if(comp < 0) {
            return searchInternal(target, node.left);
        }
        else if(comp > 0) {
            return searchInternal(target, node.right);
        }
        return node;
    }

    public Node search(T target) {
        return searchInternal(target, root);
    }

    private class Node {
        T data;
        Node left, right;

        public Node(T t) {
            data=t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BST<Integer> bst = new BST<Integer>();
        bst.insert(2);
        bst.insert(6);
        System.out.println(bst.search(2) != null);
        System.out.println(bst.search(6) != null);
        System.out.println(bst.search(8) == null);
    }
}
```